# Are there any locations for electrical boxes relative to drywall seams that cause trouble for drywalling?

Tags: drywall, junction-box

I am going to hang and mud some drywall in a small basement remodel.  I have limited experience with this - I am not expecting it to come out perfectly, but I hope for decent results.

**When planning the layout of the drywall sheets, are there particular situations I should attempt to avoid, especially with regard to electrical boxes?**

For example, in the case drawn below of an outlet box mounted to the side of a stud where two drywall seams meet vertically, the hole for the box will be cut quite near (3/4") to the edge of the drywall.  Does this create any problem as far as drywall weakness goes?  I'm assuming not, given how common this situation must be but...figured I'd ask.

[image]

Another example is below for the typical box for a switch that is 48" high on center and has cutouts from the sheets of drywall below and above.  Here, the horizontal seam for the drywall meets the box in the middle - and there is nothing supporting the drywall from behind on the side away from the stud (where the question marks are).  Are the locations depicted by the question marks at risk of weakness/wobble/movement?
[image]

Comment: I do not see any problems with that

Comment: For horizontal seams most people put blocking in so they have a nailing surface and the seams do not  move.  With a box in the way, if I had a choice I would try to move the box up/down a bit to have the blocking in, if no choice then be careful not to lean on that section of drywall.  Height of boxes do not need to be right at 4 feet.

Comment: @crip659 Is it really standard to put in blocking all along the horizontal seam?  i.e. for 16" studs, add a 14 1/2" 2x4 horizontally between each stud?

Comment: If putting the drywall horizontal, I would use blocking(personal opinion). Drywall does not need much pressure to move a bit and crack the joint mud.  Some walls do require the blocking anyway for fire stops/blocking(slowing down a fire in a wall)

Comment: Ah - that's interesting.  Totally out of curiosity, who tends to install that blocking?  Is it the framers or is it the responsibility of the drywall hangers after the decide how they're laying out the panels?

Comment: Complete non-sequitur, but your username is great 

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**For the vertical seam**, this is indeed common. To prevent crumbling at the edge, you can install the drywall then cut out the box hole. Place the drywall against the studs, apply screws without tightening them and use a utility knife in stead of a drywall saw for the vertical cut section at the stud.

Should it crumble or break anyway, remove any loose paper and crumbled pieces and don't worry about it. Simply take care of it at the mudding stage.

If you prefer to precut the hole, you can simply also remove the 3/4 strip, and again just take care of it at the mudding stage.

Note that if your stud is a door way, you need to plan for clearance between the outlet's cover plate and any door trim. A box on the stud usually does not provide enough clearance, and a short stud section (perhaps 8in of 2x4) is placed between the doorway stud and the outlet box.

Also remember you can double stud at vertical seams, thus positioning the stud edge (not stud center) at the anticipated position of the sheet edge. This is much easier to screw, and your sheet alignment is not as critical. You can use scrap wood sections as backing instead of a second full length stud.

If your stud is already placed you can simply add such backing on whichever side comes a bit short. You can add backing against the stud, above and below the outlet.

**For the horizontal seam**, it is indeed easiest if you plan the height as you have drawn, ensuring a cutout in both sheets. Kitchen counter top outlets are positioned like this.

Mudding any gaps at the top or bottom is also possible, but a little more cumbersome because you have to keep the outlet's screw hole for the receptacle or switch clear and you have to mud it so that there is strong backing for the tabs of the receptacle or switch.

For these repairs on critical seams that also may be exposed to movement, I resort to setting-type drywall ("hot mud") which is much harder than drying mud, to provide sufficient strength.

Answer (score 8):

I should note one major caveat here from P2000's otherwise fine answer

> If you prefer to precut the hole, you can simply also remove the 3/4 strip, and again just take care of it at the mudding stage.

**Don't do this**. If you're using a utility knife (which I do highly recommend), measure the hole for the box and cut the box hole out while the board is on the ground. You can cut from both sides and ensure the hole is clean. Leave the 3/4 strip as-is. If you do this right, you won't have to try and figure out how to attach that dinky strip. I've carefully cut these out myself and had no issues in putting the boards up afterward. If you measure well, you won't have to to do the "tack and cut" method P2000 mentiond

If you insist on cutting the strip out, just construction adhesive it to the stud. Fasteners are more headache than they're worth in that case.

Comment: Yes good point. There are many ways to do this, and this is a good alternative. I have often had to mud that strip on a horizontal seam and found no issue with that. The vertical seam is a different problem, since it interferes with the screw and tab as mentioned. I have had more problems pre-cutting the hole and finding it off by half an inch... so a matter of skill and experience.

Comment: I have accepted P2000's answer, but thank you for this addition to it